# Share post on LinkedIn not visible in the feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, share, linkedin-api

I'm trying to share post on LinkedIn. A successful post gives us a response like below. If I check the updateUrl my post is available, but I'm not able to see the post in LinkedIn on my home page.

```
{
  "updateKey": "UPDATE-84600926-6035330152248995840",
  "updateUrl": "https://www.linkedin.com/updates?discuss=&scope=84600926&stype=M&topic=6035330152248995840&type=U&a=aRbN"
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code used to generate that response? (obscure api key)

Comment: @linkedin_client = LinkedIn::Client.new
          @linkedin_client.authorize_from_access(user.access_token, user.access_token_secret)

          @linkedin_client.add_share({:comment => message.content,:visibility =>{:code =>"anyone"}})
          #client.update(message.content)
          message.status = :done

Comment: It's preferred you update your question when pasting code as the comments don't allow for proper styling.

Comment: @wurde Sure. Noted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post is not visible in my feed,but is visible in the feed of my connections. I am able to check all posts under recent activities.Thanks